# Is this how spring @Retryable supposed to work?

Tags: spring-boot, retrofit2, spring-retry

I recently added spring `@Retryable` to handle 502 errors instead of appropriate responses from the target server. (with retrofit2).

Below is just pseudo-code but the original code handles exceptions in a similar way.

```java
class BadGatewayException : RuntimeException

@Retryable(include = [BadGatewayException::class])
class A {

    private fun handle(block: () -> Call<T>): T {
        try {
            val response = val response = block().execute()
           
            ...      
      
            if (response.code() == 502) {
                throw BadGatewayException("The server suffers temporary connection problems.")
            }
            ...
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException("a system error has occurred")
        }
    }

}
```

I expected `@Retryable` wouldn't retry as the `BadGatewayException` that occurs with 502 would be wrapped in `RuntimeException` straight away in a catch block then thrown. But, when it was tested, it seemed like it follows this step

1. try to get a response from a retrofit request
2. 502 occurs
3. `BadGatewayException` thrown
4. retry (3 by default) - here BadGatewayException is caught somehow
5. `RuntimeException` thrown

The point is, is `@Retryable` supposed to intercept any exceptions this way? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pseudo-code you don't wrap your `BadGatewayException` into `RuntimeException`. But if you do something like `throw RuntimeException("your text", e)` where e is `BadGatewayException` I can explain what happens:
The class `AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java` which works with annotation `@Retryable` creates RetryPolicy like `return new SimpleRetryPolicy(maxAttempts, policyMap, true, retryNotExcluded);`
The third parameter is `traverseCauses` and it is always true
It means that Retryable works with causes: when it gets `RuntimeException` it takes a cause which is `BadGatewayException`. This is why retry happens in your case if you do a wrap.
I dont know how change this behavior. In the latest version (2.0.0) there is still the same code of creation a retry policy.

I know it is late but maybe it will be helpful for someone

Comment: That's exactly what I found out debugging. Thank you very much! I've just accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

The `SimpleRetryPolicy` used by the annotation does not traverse the `cause` chain to look for classified exceptions; only the top level exception is compared to the classified list.

You would have to wire up your own `RetryInterceptor` with an appropriately configured `RetryTemplate` and `SimpleRetryPolicy`.

```java
    /**
     * Create a builder for a stateless retry interceptor.
     * @return The interceptor builder.
     */
    public static StatelessRetryInterceptorBuilder stateless() {
        return new StatelessRetryInterceptorBuilder();
    }
```

```java
RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
    .retryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy(...))
    .build();
```

See

```java
    /**
     * Create a {@link SimpleRetryPolicy} with the specified number of retry attempts. If
     * traverseCauses is true, the exception causes will be traversed until a match or the
     * root cause is found. The default value indicates whether to retry or not for
     * exceptions (or super classes thereof) that are not found in the map.
     * @param maxAttempts the maximum number of attempts
     * @param retryableExceptions the map of exceptions that are retryable based on the
     * map value (true/false).
     * @param traverseCauses true to traverse the exception cause chain until a classified
     * exception is found or the root cause is reached.
     * @param defaultValue the default action.
     */
    public SimpleRetryPolicy(int maxAttempts, Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> retryableExceptions,
            boolean traverseCauses, boolean defaultValue) {
```

(`defaultValue = true` and `Map.of(BadGatewayException.class, false)`).

Set the bean name of the interceptor in the `interceptor` annotation property.

Comment: This doesn't match the behavior I am seeing.  In a Spring Boot application using the `@Retryable` annotation, if the thrown exception does not match any `@Retryable.include` class but the thrown exception's cause does, the method is retried.  This behavior happens with the latest version (1.3.3), as well as the version that introduced `@Retryable` (1.1.0.RELEASE).